# Javascript tolower/ignoreCase in filter

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to make a filter for a list of spans im having trouble putting what is in the spans to lower case or ignorecase. 
Any ideas?

```
 $("#filterinput2").keyup(function () {
            var filter = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase(); // get the value of the input, which we filter on
            console.log("lower filter" + filter);
            if (filter) {         
                // hide tr's for songs not matching and show tr's for songs matching
                $(".tonelist").find(".song:not(:contains(filter))").parent().parent().parent().fadeOut("slow");
                $(".tonelist").find(".song:contains(filter)").parent().parent().parent().fadeIn();
                if (window.console != undefined) {
                    console.log($(".tonelist").find(".song:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().parent().parent().innerHTML);
                }

                $(".tonelist").find(".grouptitle:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().fadeOut("slow");
                $(".tonelist").find(".grouptitle:contains(" + filter + ")").parent().fadeIn();
                if (window.console != undefined)
                    console.log($(".tonelist").find(".grouptitle:not(:contains(" + filter + "))").parent().parent().parent().innerHTML);
            } else
            // if input field is empty, show all tr's
                $(".tonelist").find("tr").fadeIn();

            ColorLines();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to check the contents of each of those spans yourself.  You can do that by using the .html() function to get the contents of each song/grouptitle as a string.  Something like this might work (although I haven't tested it):

```
    $("#filterinput2").keyup(function () {
        var filter = ($(this).val()).toLowerCase(); // get the value of the input, which we filter on
        console.log("lower filter" + filter);
        if (filter) {         
            // hide tr's for songs not matching and show tr's for songs matching
            spans = $(".tonelist").find(".song, .grouptitle")
            for (s in spans) {
                el = $(spans[s]);
                if ( el.html().match( new RegExp(filter, "i") ) ) {
                    el.fadeIn();
                } else {
                    el.fadeOut("slow");
                }
            }
        } else
        // if input field is empty, show all tr's
            $(".tonelist").find("tr").fadeIn();

        ColorLines();
    });
```

The reason is that the :contains() css selector is case-sensitive, and there's no way I know of to change that.